# Provisioning lists on site creation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, provisioning

What would be the way to go about this in SP2013/Online?

I would like to have it so that if a user were to create a subsite, a custom "Comments" list is automatically created as well?

I was thinking of activating a feature that will provision this list, but perhaps there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be looking at Remote Provisioning using provider hosted app.

The following steps will be covered under this approach:

1. Override create sub site link with hook to provider hosted app (if we    target sub site creation)
2. Actual template selection is coming from provider hosted app side based on configuration – abstraction layer to provider different variations of the oob sits
3. Different templates and capabilities are handled in the provider hosted app side based on requirements, no configurations in the SharePoint side
4. Sites are provisioned based on configuration using CSOM/REST. All sites are created based on oob site definitions, but are then modified based on configurations
5. All features and functionalities associated to oob sites are activated and additional changes are applied, like master pages or themes uploaded and applied to sites

Details of the actual implementation and further information is available here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2013/08/23/site-provisioning-techniques-and-remote-provisioning-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to get a list created with a site. Isn't there an option to update some XML anymore?